# Jump cooldown implementation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement cooldown for actions in my game - prevent same action from happening for some time. I.e. the character should jump only once in 3 seconds even if user presses "jump" button more often than that.

For some reason the `jumpCooldown` just gets stuck at like 2 and won't move on thus making my cooldown infinite.

In particular why `jumpCooldown` does not get to 0 and how to fix this code? I'm also open to other better approaches for implementing cooldown?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExperminetMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    static bool canJump = true;
    public float jumpCooldown = 3f;

    void Start() { }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            canJump = CoolDownFunction();
        } 
    }
    public bool CoolDownFunction()
    {
        jumpCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (jumpCooldown <= 0)
        {
            jumpCooldown = 3f;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any help is appreciated" is not a question -- do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: "for some reason the time.deltatime just gets stuck at like 2 and won't move on. Thus making my cooldown infinite."

Comment: "This code is much clearer and easier to understand" It may be for you, but the problem can still seem vague to others. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve with this code (e.g. only allowing the user to jump once every three seconds)? That may help others in helping you find a solution and avoid speculative answers.

Comment: @devNull yeah,but time.deltatime just gets stuck for some reason

Comment: @EyalGelberg I've edited the post - please review. Note that I don't think "time.deltatime just gets stuck" is what you actually mean - I've edited it to "jumpCooldown just gets stuck at like 2" which is what *should* be happening with code you have. If you disagree with edit please don't just revert but edit in a similar way so it asks your question but does not include unrelated text as original version.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov you explained it very well,that is exactly what I meant. I didn't know that the point it got stuck in has any value, but it sure is stuck at 2. Could you help me resolve this with your method?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 3):

Your Update function is written as

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
{
    CoolDownFunction();
}
```

This means that your cooldown is only being updated while the user is holding down the spacebar (**Correction**: For one frame. GetKey gets the current status).  Instead, the jump cooldown time should be updated every frame (at least until `canJump` becomes `true`), and `canJump` should only be set to `false` if the user attempts to jump while `canJump` is true.

You need to separate out your jump cooldown from your jump request.

Also, once your user successfully jumps, `canJump` is set to false, so your `CoolDownFunction` will never run again, since your conditional will always be false.

Comment: I've tried tons of combinations that honestly I cannot look at this anymore with a collective mind. If you could write a semi-working example or just my code with your fixes I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Personally I think better way would be to just remember last time of jump and compare... but indeed doing it every frame (as `deltaTime` is per-frame: "The completion time in seconds since the last frame") is indeed the right approach.

Comment: @EyalGelberg: Just copy the example from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html .  Note that this takes the approach recommended by Alexei, rather than the approach you attempted.

Comment: Just tried that @Brian,doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov how would you go about doing that?I'm open for suggestions as long as it works

Comment: @EyalGelberg the link Brian provided is exactly what I suggested. I don't see any simpler way of doing it (and can't see what you could have done so it "doesn't seem to work").

Comment: `This means that your cooldown is only being updated while the user is holding down the spacebar` this is exactly **wrong**! It is called only **once** for each time the key is pressed! That is why it is always reduced by just a little bit... A while the button stays down would rather be `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)`

Comment: DerHugo is correct; GetKeyDown only returns true for one frame.  Mind you, GetKey would still be wrong, for the reasons I discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [IEnumerator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) for this along with

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(jumpCooldown);
```

So something like:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    static bool canJump = true;
    public float jumpCooldown = 3f;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            // Put your jump code here.
            StartCoroutine(CoolDownFunction());
        }
    }
    IEnumerator CoolDownFunction()
    {
        canJump = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(jumpCooldown);
        canJump = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not really acquainted with that type yet, but if you could please build a working code I would appreciate it

Comment: Hey. I added the full code. Hope it makes sense. ^_^ It might not be the best, I'm a messy coder.